# What does if (! variable_name) mean in c language

Tags: c

Here is the problem

```
int main() {
    int pid = fork();
    if (!pid) {
        // condition 1
    } else {
        // condition 2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What does `(!pid)` do?

Comment: This should have been mentioned in ***any*** decent C tutorial...

Comment: This is not "a doubt". It's a **question**. Sigh. I know this is futile, but it's so difficult to get used to this usage. :)

Comment: what it does, after some testing, seems to be 'x==0?1:0 ' it will therefore only return 0 or 1 . it is not a binary operator like all the others and most certainly not a binary inversion.

in the context here, it decides whether after the fork(), the program came out as the original process (parent) or it's new clone (child)

Answer (score 10):

It is equivalent to:

```
if (!pid != 0) /* ... */
```

And then:

```
if (pid == 0) /* ... */
```

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**
>
> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares
>   unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`.
>   The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

Comment: @TimPost OP hadn't make the effort to learn basic C syntax reasonably well. He deserves being confused, +1 here for a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. So it is either (!(pid != 0)) or (pid ==0) ..right!!

Comment: The reason a programmer writes !pid is not because they are trying to simplify !pid != 0. The reason they write it is because they are one lazy bum who types so slow that they couldn't possibly manage to write out pid==0. Instead, they abuse the boolean logic operators, since those yield int and not bool in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin Another reason to write it like this is that it might be easier/faster to read and interpret.

Comment: @H2CO3 With that logic, the best answer would be that `!pid` is an simpler way of writing `!!!pid`.

Comment: @Zecc If someone fails to read and understand the meaning of `pid == 0` in a reasonable amount of time, they shouldn't be doing C programming in the first place. And then there is the case of pointers, where an explicit check against NULL, `ptr == NULL`, is clearer. Compare `if(!*ptr || !ptr)` with `if(*ptr == 0 || ptr == NULL)`. The former has a great potential for bugs and confusion.

Comment: You may scoff at this type of question but it does tend to provoke a discussion of good coding practices.

Comment: @Lundin Alright, I'm sold. (I think you meant `if(ptr == NULL || *ptr == 0)` though)

Comment: @Zecc Ah yes of course. It would be a tad bit silly to check the contents of a NULL pointer :)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!pid)
```

Is as you wrote:

```
if(pid == 0) {
  /* do something */
}
```

And then:

```
if(pid)
```

is

```
if(pid != 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The !-operator negates a logical condition.

In C, a numerical value of 0 is considered a logical false, any other numerical value a logical true. The !-operator negates a logical condition, so when pid is 0 it's true and when pid is not 0, it's false.

You could read it as "when there is no pid".

Answer (score 3):

It means negation.  In your case `condition 1` will be executed in a parent process, `condition 2` in a child process.

Comment: +1 For mentioning what it means in this case, as related to threads; i.e. `fork` is guaranteed to return 0 is the parent thread and not zero is the child thread.

Comment: condition 1 in child thread isn't it ?

Comment: @user1630845 Nope, `0` as pid refers to parent process

Comment: Zecc your answer explained enough but can you be a bit more clear please.

Comment: @ Roman You are right but it's returned to child process. And also parent process gets the PID of the child. Plz correct me if i am wrong. :D

Answer (score 2):

`!pid` expression will be true if `pid` equals to zero.

Basically, it's the same as:

```
if (pid == 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain old C there is not boolean data type but there is boolean logic.

Numeric values all evaluate to `true` except for 0 which evaluates to `false`.

The consequence of this is the fact that if you want to test if a condition is true you are in fact comparing it to 0.

Comparison operators in C yield a `true` or `false` result meaning they return a numeric 1 or 0.

The negation operator inverts `true` into `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Things that are false:
false, 0, null
Things that are true:
everything else.

For if !pid to be true, pid would need to be 0, false, or null

Answer (score 0):

`(!pid)` is equivalent to  `(pid == 0)`

Actually, the code in the question is bugged. `fork()` can return one of three things:

`>0`  The process id of the child process. This is returned to the parent.

`0`  This is returned to the child.

`<0`  Failure. This is returned to the parent.

Check [this tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html) for the proper use of the return value from `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess all the answers posted are correct. In one line, (!pid) would be equivalent to (pid==0).
I however take the opportunity to explain how/why it is used here.

[`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) function will create a subprocess A.K.A. child process. So when the function returns, at that instance there will be 2 processes, which are executing at the same location code-wise. Thus it will return in two copies of the process - we call them as parent & child.

The return value of `fork()` is the [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the child, when it is returning in the parent process. & it is = 0 in child process. In your code, `pid = fork();` will capture this return value.

If (pid==0) then you are in child process. If (pid != 0) you are in parent process. Based on whether you are in parent or child, you can change the behavior of your code. (e.g. you may call exec in child & wait in parent.)

For more details about fork function, google for `fork()`.